# jsPlumb - How to get anchor's position

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to save and load a jsPlumb flowchart, but I'm having a problem when recreating the connections. They are overlapping each other when I try to load it. Image 1 shows how I saved the flowchart and Image 2 shows how it is loaded.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620719/save-and-load-jsplumb-flowchart-including-exact-anchors-and-connections) topic and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665304/jsplumb-new-connection-handler-how-to-get-the-endpoint-anchor-position) one and using `endpoint.anchor.x` and `endpoint.anchor.y` or `connectionInfo.sourceEndpoint.anchor.x` or `connectionInfo.sourceEndpoint.anchor.y` simple doesn't work. If I print it with `console.log` it shows `undefined` . I don't know if it's something about version or whatever but it looks like 'anchor' doesn't have 'x' and 'y'. I'm using jsPlumb 1.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I printed my `connection` with `console.log` to see its properties and I solved my problem using 
`connection.endpoints[0].endpoint.x` 
`connection.endpoints[0].endpoint.y` 
`connection.endpoints[1].endpoint.x` 
`connection.endpoints[1].endpoint.y`

where: 0 is the source endpoint; 1 is the target endpoint; x and y are their respectives X and Y coordinates

**UPDATE**
The details are now contained within `anchor` object of `endpoint` as :

`connection.endpoints[0].anchor.x` 
`connection.endpoints[0].anchor.y` 
`connection.endpoints[1].anchor.x` 
`connection.endpoints[1].anchor.y`

Comment: how do you redraw the connections with anchors x & y ? Can you please share some code!

Comment: @coding_idiot First I recreate the connection: connection = instance.connect({ source: sourceId, target: targetId });
and then I set it with : connection.endpoints[0].endpoint.x = xSource; 
 connection.endpoints[0].endpoint.y = ySource; 
 connection.endpoints[1].endpoint.x = xTarget; 
 connection.endpoints[1].endpoint.y = yTarget;

If you want me to be more clearer don't bother to ask I'll be happy to help you

Comment: I was able to do the same. Currently, I'm facing this issue - We have a flow-chart, there are 2 end-points in each component, we of course not use both end-points. But then when we restore the diagram, we should show those un-used empty endpoints. I quickly went through http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connect-examples but found no help.

Comment: I didn't get it straight. What you mean by "show those un-used empty endpoints"? I also use FlowChart but with only 1 endpoint and I don't see a problem if using more than 1.. I'm recreating my component using instance.makeSource(...) and instance.makeTarget(...), so that I'll have my component with 1 endpoint (there wouldn't be a problem if there were more), and then I set the connections using the code I wrote above

Comment: `makeSource` and `makeTarget` works fine, but then we can't drag appropriately. Anyways, I was able to figure out the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my jsplumb here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m7nercLh/2/

You can create a flowchart, and save the json. Reload the page, paste in the saved json, and click load, and it will recreate your flowchart, saving the co-ordinates of all your objects and connections.

The code to get the anchors position is here:

```
    $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
    connections.push({
        connectionId: connection.id,
        pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
        pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
        anchors: $.map(connection.endpoints, function(endpoint) {

            return [[endpoint.anchor.x, 
            endpoint.anchor.y, 
            endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[0], 
            endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[1],
            endpoint.anchor.offsets[0],
            endpoint.anchor.offsets[1]
        ]];

  })
    });
});
```